# How to find data of a period when the date format in is american date style

Tags: sql, oracle, date

TABLE NAME = CONTRACT_DATA

```
CONTRACT    DATE
A           10/25/2019
B           06/20/2019
C           10/01/2019
D           10/05/2019
```

Query:

```
select * 
from CONTRACT_DATA
WHERE DATE(VALUE_DATE,'MM/DD/YYYY') > '10/01/2019' AND 
      DATE(VALUE_DATE,'MM/DD/YYYY') < '10/31/2019'
```

Tried to get the data in Oct month but failed

Required output A,C,D

Comment: What is the data type of column VALUE_DATE?

Comment: Better change data type to `DATE` rather than string.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to convert your string to date for comparison, using `TO_DATE()`; on the other side of the operator, for fixed values, you can use a `DATE` litteral:

```
SELECT *
FROM contract_data
WHERE 
    TO_DATE(value_date, 'MM/DD/YYY') > DATE'2019-10-01'
    AND TO_DATE(value_date, 'MM/DD/YYY') < DATE'2019-10-31'
```

Note: if you want the *entire* month, then you need to ajust the boundaries

```
SELECT *
FROM contract_data
WHERE 
    TO_DATE(value_date, 'MM/DD/YYY') >= DATE'2019-10-01'
    AND TO_DATE(value_date, 'MM/DD/YYY') < DATE'2019-11-01'
```

Comment: This will include 2019-11-01 also in output

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle a `DATE` data type always has a year, month, day, hour, minute and second components. Your user interface may not show the time component but it is always there. If its not specified then it will default to `00:00:00` (midnight) but you should not rely on this.

Also, dates do not have a format. They are stored internally as 7 bytes (2 for year and 1 for each other month-second component). It is the user interface you are using that will implicitly apply a format to your data when you want to display it so that it is meaningful to the user.

You can specify dates using:

- ANSI date literals: `DATE '2019-10-01'`
- ANSI timestamp literals: `TIMESTAMP '2019-10-01 12:34:56'` (and Oracle will cast it to a date as needed)
- The `TO_DATE` function: `TO_DATE( '10/01/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY' )`

If you have a `DATE` column then do not use `TO_DATE` on it as it is already a `DATE`; instead just compare it to another `DATE`.

If you want the dates for October 2019 then you need to find the values between `2019-10-01 00:00:00` and `2019-10-31 23:59:59` and the simplest way to do this is to find values that are greater than or equal to midnight of the first day of the month and less than midnight of the first day of the next month:

**Test Data**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE contract_data (
  CONTRACT   CHAR(1),
  VALUE_DATE DATE
);

INSERT INTO contract_data
SELECT 'A', DATE '2019-10-25' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', DATE '2019-06-20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', DATE '2019-10-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'D', DATE '2019-10-05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'E', TIMESTAMP '2019-10-31 23:59:59' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   contract_data
WHERE  VALUE_DATE >= DATE '2019-10-01'
AND    VALUE_DATE <  DATE '2019-11-01'
```

**Output**:

> ```
> CONTRACT | VALUE_DATE
> :------- | :---------
> A        | 10/25/2019
> C        | 10/01/2019
> D        | 10/05/2019
> E        | 10/31/2019
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6a47cd2b1f17943dc0747a18d5f98458)*

Answer (score 0):

If your date is stored as string in the table then you can simply use the `to_date` function and `DATE` literal as following:

```
select * 
  from CONTRACT_DATA
 WHERE TO_DATE(VALUE_DATE,'MM/DD/YYYY') 
       BETWEEN DATE '2019-10-01' AND DATE '2019-10-31'
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Why??? `to_date` includes only `mm/dd/yyyy`. There is no time part. So for 31-oct any time it will be 31-oct.

Comment: If the `VALUE_DATE` column is a `DATE` data type (as implied by the column name) then Oracle will perform an implicit conversion from a `DATE` to a string using the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` as `TO_DATE` expects a string as the first argument. If any user changes their session parameters to a different value then the query will fail as the implicit date format won't match.

Comment: That is why I have mentioned that if column is of varchar data type then my answer will be useful.